# What is the meaning of fork() and grep in Linux?

Tags: linux, api, grep, fork

As a non-native English speaker, I have difficulty remembering Linux commands compared to other APIs. In Linux, the function names don't seem to indicate their purpose.

Why is the name `fork()` chosen to create a child process? In the dictionary, `fork` means "a utensil with two or more prongs", which is unrelated to creating a new process.

Why is the name `grep` chosen to "print lines matching a pattern"? Does `grep` mean "g report"?

Where can I find the etymology behind other commands in the Linux API?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep. Fork is about creating a branch - and it's what it actually do: creating copy of your process; what will you do with this copy is up to you, so it couldn't be called anything else.

Comment: *A utensil with two or more prongs* emerging from a single shaft, you can't see an analogy here?

Comment: Just to tell others who comes across this post, there are some websites  telling learners about what is the meaning of names of LINUX APIs and Commands, like "http://en.wikipedia.org/" and "http://linux.about.com/"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fork can mean to split in two, as a road ([source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fork)).

> Fork (15): to divide into branches.

[Grep's etymology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grep#Etymology):

> From an idiomatic command sequence in the qed and ed text editors: ‘g/re/p’, meaning: globally search for a regular expression and print.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258509/etymology-of-linux-commands) lists the etymology of some Linux commands.

Comment: "globally search for a regular expression and print." Oh, this is exactly what I want!! Now I have a very good comprehension about "grep" and remember it well. By the way, could you tell me where I can find such explanations for those API names? Is there any site for this kind of things?

Comment: Thanks so much,Andy! I searched "globally search for a regular expression and print." via google, now I have known some websites which tell the meaning of the LINUX API names.

Comment: @StevePeng: It might be a good idea to post your own answer giving these links that you've found useful.

Answer (score 1):

[www.lockergnome.com/uncategorized/2006/08/21/linux-forks](http://www.lockergnome.com/uncategorized/2006/08/21/linux-forks)

> Linux forks, **a term often applied to the varieties of Linux
>   distributions**, are poorly understood even in the Linux community.
>   Are all the various distributions available on the internet true forks
>   of the kernal? Kevin Morgan argues that they are not. Is his
>   Enterprise OpenSource Magazine (formerly LinuxWorld Magazine) article
>   “Linux Technology Leadership and the Forking Issue”, he explores the
>   concept of forking in detail, explains the advantages of having unique
>   variants for distinct applications and explains why variants are not
>   forks.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it's correct for a different question than was asked.  The two meanings are loosely related though: a "fork" of a project is initially identical to the "parent", just as the child process created by the fork() system call is identical to its parent.